# Using JSON_TABLE to save an unorder ARRAY

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, json-table

I have the next array, I need to save in a json_table, the problem They are shown in different order for each employee For that reason I can't store using:

```
Depto varchar(100) path '$.plaza.nodosEstructura[1].Descripcion',
```

My json is:

```
"plaza": {
            "employee": 19769,
            "nodosEstructura": [
                {
                    "estructura": 5,
                    "descripcion": "IMI 2"
                },
                {
                    "estructura": 1,
                    "descripcion": "TKS"
                }
            ]
},
"plaza": {
            "employee": 19770,
            "nodosEstructura": [               
                {
                    "estructura": 1,
                    "descripcion": "INDUSTRIAL"
                },
         {
                    "estructura": 5,
                     "descripcion": "IMI 1"
                }
            ]
}
```

I need to save in a table using the next estructure:

| Employee | Estructura1 | Estructura5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19769 | TKS | IMI 2 |
| 19770 | INDUSTRIAL | IMI 1 |

Could you help me please =(

Order in a json_table an unordered array

Comment: So why don't you sort the entries in your JSON first then?

Comment: I receive it from a supplier and they have not been able to order it

Comment: *My json is* .. incorrect. Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). Also provide **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: you can't have duplicate key `plaza` in a single JSON object.

Comment: If you need to get the value of `estructura` into a column name, you will have to [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql?noredirect=1&lq=1) the result of `JSON_TABLE()`.